# Seeking your advice or best practice for building shared Angular Forms

Tags: angular, forms

I have a couple of pages (two or more) each containing a form. This form has many (let's say about fifty) form controls inside. However, a few (two or three) of the controls are different to the other form.

e.g.

PageA.component.html

- Form A

  - Form Control (input text)
  - Form Control (button)
  - Form Control (enabled button)
  - ...(another nearly hundreds of form controls)

PageB.component.html

- Form B

  - Form Control (input text)
  - Form Control (button)
  - Form Control (disabled button)
  - ...(another nearly hundreds of form controls)

I am thinking about two approaches to implement it:

First one is to implement multiple pages (with multiple forms respectively) as like the illustration above. The pros is that the implementation will be straight forward  and simpler. The cons is that it will contain huge amount of boilerplate code for the alike form controls and application logic.

Second one is to implement multiple pages which share the same a child component with the form controls. And specific application logic will be added to those form controls which are different among the pages. The pros is that it reduce the boilerplate code. The cons is that the communication between parent-child component may become complex as it involves numerous amount of form controls.

e.g.

PageA.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]='myFormGroup'>
  <app-my-custom-child-with-form-controls [input-data-to-differentiate-page-b]='some-A-data'></app-my-custom-child-with-form-controls>
</form>
```

PageB.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]='myFormGroup'>
  <app-my-custom-child-with-form-controls [input-data-to-differentiate-page-a]='some-B-data'></app-my-custom-child-with-form-controls>
</form>
```

p.s.: Angular 7 Reactive Forms will be adopted

Excuse me that it's quite abstract for me to depict the problem very clearly.
Please let me know if more clarifications are needed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Have you thought maybe generating an array of the data of all similar FormControls and generate a form based on this array? Also make a "unique" array for each page's unique Form Controls and add those to the array generated above.

Comment: Thanks @RonRofe for your suggestion! It could make the similar FormControls shared among the pages with the same typescript file. However, it still needs two same snippets form control codes in two component html files, isn't it? (Correct me if I understood it wrongly). Still, thank you for your great idea.

Comment: On the other hand, I've come across one thing called Control Value Accessors as mentioned in this blog: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d. It seems it may be able to resolve my problem (though it requires more advanced skill). I'd give it a try and come back for the result.

Comment: As far as I know the use of CVA is designed to serve custom form fields but not groups. Your article seems to be something new for me - I'll read it. But in general it looks like this is the particular solution you have been looking for.